# Images not showing in the app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

This is something weird happening on my partners iphones,
my phone shows all the images and videos correctly , attaching some screenshots
[image]

[image]

As you can see thats my iPhone 5s running ios 9.2.1, not only that it works perfectly on all my simulators.

Now I gave the code to my partner but when he runs on all his testing iPhones running ios 9.2.1, it doesn't show any image or video, attaching screenshot of my partners phone.

[image]

[image]

Things we have tried,
1. tried upgrading the mac os, 
2. tried degrading the mac os
3. tried upgraded ios phone
4. tried on older ios version as well.
5. sharing the same code 2 times.

We both are using the latest xcode 7.2
What could be issue?

Comment: Is there a chance that the path to the images is local path on your mac and not relative ?

Comment: Please provide more details about how you set up the images to be displayed. There are many ways you could have done it.

Comment: from where you load the images, from a web service or inside your project, and did you use or not `autolayout` for your app.

Comment: @shannoga we are using Parse database,

Comment: @Kurt Revis simple auto layout, this is the 15th build, it worked fine all before

Comment: @Graham using autolayout and Parse database

Comment: we can show an image in many ways.so what did you use  an `imageView` or `webViwe`.and the other thing is without images, what about othre data,are those ok. it is better to give us more details.

Comment: @Graham imageview ofcourse.

Comment: So if it is parse - do you have any specific permissions in the Parse console for this image field ?

Comment: @shannoga there is nothing like that, it worked perfectly before.